# Image is not generating/uploading in the server

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, server

I am developing an android app in which i want to save images on server(free server 000webhost).To do this i am encoding my image into string using base64. And sending this string with the POST method using volley.
But the image is not generating on the server side. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

upload.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "id8258200_image";
$username = "id8258200_qmine1";
$password = "";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

echo "Connected successfully";

 if(isset($_POST["image"])){

$encoded_string = $_POST["image"];

$image_name="img";
$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$path = "image/$image_name.jpeg";

$file = fopen($path, 'wb');

$is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);
echo "success";
 }
 else {
      echo "error";
 }
?>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "https://qmine.000webhostapp.com/question/upload.php";


private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("tr", "qwerty" + encodedImage);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage() {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "errorrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String img = getStringImage(bitmap);
            Log.d("qw", "aasas" + img);
            Params.put("image", img);
            return Params;

        }

    };

    queue.add(request);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if (v == buttonUpload) {
        uploadImage();
    }

    if (v == buttonView) {
        viewImage();
    }
}

private void viewImage() {
    // startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageListView.class));
}
}
```

Comment: echo base64 string in php file and check if string is there so you will exactly find that problem is with decode and save image on server side or android side unable to send base64

so just "echo $encoded_string ;die()" and you will be near to find problem

You can also verify if string is valid by using following website which convert base64 to image

https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: I checked base64 string is right and i'm getting exact image in the above site.

Comment: that means all thing works expect save image to server so check permission of folder where you save your image and also log error for image save fail.

Comment: I've given all the permissions to the folder

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me. Seems like a permission issue. Add these lines to top of your PHP script.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // telling PHP to explicitly print all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Show all notices, warnings and fatal errors
```

Second thing to check if the folder is having enough permission to write a file. Give write permission if not there and see if the code works.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: It shows no error .It only displays "connected successfully" message nothing else.Image file is still not generated in the server

Comment: Also I've given all permissions to the folder.